# How to load library in JS repl in a yarn project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I have a project with a package.json file, generated by YARN.

How can I load a js REPL and load a library that's specified in the package.json file?

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 1):

With `npm` or with `yarn` you can download and install locally all the dependencies specified in a `package.json` file.

First thing is to run the install command:

```sh
my-project $ npm install
```

or

```sh
my-project $ npm install
```

This command is going to install locally all the dependencies in your package.json file.

Now you should have a new folder `node_modules` that contains all the code.

On a js file:

```js
// index.js
const myLib = require('myLib')
```

Now you can work with the library.